# GROUP BY partly

Tags: mysql

I have table:

```
ID_table, User, Multi_ID, Action, Date, ... 
100     , JN    , 0     , test1 , 1.1.2017
101     , DK    , 51    , test2 , 3.1.2017
102     , JN    , 51    , test2 , 3.1.2017
103     , LP    , 0     , test3 , 3.1.2017
104     , DK    , 52    , test4 , 5.1.2017
105     , LP    , 52    , test4 , 5.1.2017
106     , KH    , 52    , test4 , 5.1.2017
```

I would like make GROUP BY Multi_ID, but only for Multi_ID > 0.
If Multi_ID = 0 - without GROUP BY ...:

```
Date      Users      Action
1.1.2017  (JN)       test1
3.1.2017  (DK,JN)    test2
3.1.2017  (LP)       test3
5.1.2017  (DK,LP,KH) test4
```

There is my code without solution Multi_ID = 0

```
$sql="SELECT * , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT User separator ',' ) AS Us    
      FROM table
  GROUP BY Multi_ID
  ORDER BY Date ASC";
$result = MySQL_Query($sql);
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: In a single query - no, it is not possible. Group by applies to the entire resultset. What you can do is to write 2 separate queries and combine them using `union`. However, your 2nd query does no make any sense, since it has a single aggregate function without a group by that will collapse the resultset into a single record. Therefore the `select *` part does not make any sense. You must describe in a great detail as to what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: @Shadow i think it's possible. One can introduce a new column, equal to `Multi_ID` for `Multi_ID > 0`, and a new Guid otherwise, and group on that.

Comment: In your query you don't care which action and date to fetch for Multi_IDs 51 and 52. It would be better to do so (e.g. go for `MAX` or `MIN`) or explicitly say you don't care (with `ANY_VALUE`). And if they are supposed to be all the same for each Multi_ID > 0, then you may want to re-think your data model so as to remove redundancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two queries the result of which you glue together with `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT date, user AS users, action
FROM mytable
WHERE multi_id = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  MAX(date) AS date, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user SEPARATOR ',' ) AS users,
  MAX(action) AS action
FROM mytable
WHERE multi_id > 0
GROUP BY multi_id
ORDER BY date;
```

Another option is to group by `UUID` in case of `Multi_ID = 0`, so as to keep them separate. This may be both more elegant and less easy to understand ;-)

```
SELECT 
  MAX(date) as date, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user SEPARATOR ',' ) AS users,
  MAX(action) as action
FROM mytable
GROUP BY CASE WHEN multi_id = 0 THEN uuid() ELSE multi_id END
ORDER BY date;
```